# Meaning of AにBを+adverb+する

Tags: grammar, particle-に

Regarding WTO announcement on the Korean import ban of fish from Fukushima etc:

> ＷＴＯは２３日、「輸入の禁止は差別で、韓国は**必要以上に貿易の決まりを厳しくしている**」と言いました。
>   On the 23rd the WTO said that the import ban is discriminatory and, South Korea are *making the trade rules more strict than necessary*.

I'm having trouble parsing the part in bold.

する doesn't translate well as 'make' here. The WTO makes the rules, not the Koreans. Can する mean 'interpret' in this context?

On its own I would translate 決まりを厳しくする as 'make the rules strict'. Again if する could mean 'interpret' then I could treat 寂しく adverbially and get 'interpreting the rules strictly' which would make more sense.

Finally, I'm struggling with how to join 必要以上に to all of this. I'm familiar with the construct AにBをする 'make B (into) A', but if I use this I get 'make the rules more than necessary' which is nonsense.

How do I put all these pieces together to make something meaningful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you make an adverb from a noun by adding に?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24466/can-you-make-an-adverb-from-a-noun-by-adding-%e3%81%ab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the word 'make' here is appropriate. Korea is unilaterally 'making' their own set of 'rules' (decisions) or modifying existing decisions in contrast with what the WTO has suggested or ruled on.

If you don't like the word 'make', I would suggest 'implement'.

As far as what is being done 'more than necessary', it would be the 'strictness' of the implementation. 必要以上厳しくしている.

> 韓国は必要以上に（貿易の決まりを）厳しくしている。

Korea is making the (implementation of the) trade decision (to restrict import of fish) more strict than is necessary. (in a manner which exceeds their mandate).

Comment: Your bracketing of the sentence helps. I think now that 必要以上に adverbially modifies 厳しく to give 'more strictly than necessary'. Is that how you understand it?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is.